# Is there a way for using $where operator to get data that contains specified strings in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, where-clause, operator-keyword

Current JSON object is

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"613ed8098709b6402ab91ddd"},"employeeid":1187,"name":"John Steight","salary":75000},
{"_id":{"$oid":"613ed8788709b6402ab91dde"},"employeeid":2455,"name":"Syed","salary":90000},
{"_id":{"$oid":"613ed8c78709b6402ab91ddf"},"employeeid":24113,"name":"Wright John","salary":65000}
```

Use the `$where` operator to find employees where the name contains John

Here is my command:

```
db.HR.find({$where: "this.name == /$John$/"}).
```

It returned nothing.

Answer (score 2):

If want to use `$where`, you should pass it a valid JavaScript expression. You can do it like this:

```
db.collection.find({
  $where: "this.name.includes('John')"
})
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SUynzrp2j25)

Note that you don't have to use `$where`. You can do it with `$regex`, like this:

```
db.collection.find({
  name: { "$regex": "John" }
})
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/roLchxpIPfM)

Comment: Thank you so much. I know how to use $regex, but I was trying to use $where instead

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it now?

Comment: Welcome. Consider also upvoting and accepting my answer if it helped you.